# Loop "Allow Access" script over range of fileIDs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to scripting and trying to bash together a script for completing the "Allow Access" message box for new importrange formulas.

**Background**

I have regular extract of data (in csv file) from a reporting tool, I want to combine this data into a google sheets "dashboard" (as reporting tool doesn't do this itself).  I have one main spreadsheet where I'm pulling each "extract file" into using importrange.  Separate sheet for each csv file.  I'm aiming to then use this one main spreadsheet for the dashboard, therefore only ever one spreadsheet link.

What I have already done
I have a script that picks up fileIDs from a specific GDrive folder and pulls into a list in a sheet.

Example list:

| File Name | Tab Name | File ID | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ScheduleSummaryExport (NS) | Summary NS | 1AxBNFtm25R6vyI1Aw499W04xS_TNA3zRf7HFXogS7DY | "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AxBNFtm25R6vyI1Aw499W04xS_TNA3zRf7HFXogS7DY" |
| ScheduleSummaryExport (CS) | Summary CS | 1aoW0cXgWr2eCTV_wUtydHPtCDI99NOtRWshYeCPjI04 | "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aoW0cXgWr2eCTV_wUtydHPtCDI99NOtRWshYeCPjI04" |

From here I have each sheet tab with an importrange formula such as:

=importrange(FileIDs!D2,"ScheduleSummaryExport (NS).csv!A1:L1000")

Now when I put new files in the folder and run my script it refreshes with the new fileID and then each sheet tab then pops up with the "Allow Access" request.  This here lies the problem.

I have found script details that works if I directly add the source file ID manually into the script

```
function addImportrangePermission() {
  // id of the spreadsheet to add permission to import
  const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  // donor or source spreadsheet id, you should get it somewhere
  const donorId = '#####';

  // adding permission by fetching this url
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ssId}/externaldata/addimportrangepermissions?donorDocId=${donorId}`;

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  const params = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```

But I now want to improve this and have it pick up the "donorId" from my sheet tab above column File ID (C).  So I have tried the below, but it doesn't seem to be working, there are no errors, but just not doing what it should.

```
function donorID() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('FileIDs');
  const filenames = ss.getRange('C2:C8').getValues();
  const IDs = [];

  filenames.forEach(fn=>{

  // id of the spreadsheet to add permission to import
  const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  const donorId = filenames

  // adding permission by fetching this url
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ssId}/externaldata/addimportrangepermissions?donorDocId=${donorId}`;

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  const params = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
})}
```

Anything anybody can do to help me here, would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, `filenames` is an array. And, the ID of `fn` is not used. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, UrlFetchApp is run in a loop. **Please confirm the sheet name "FileIDs" and column again.**

```js
function donorID() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('FileIDs');
  const ids = ss.getRange('C2:C' + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().filter(([c]) => c);
  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  ids.forEach(donorId => {
    const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ssId}/externaldata/addimportrangepermissions?donorDocId=${donorId}`;
    const params = {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  });
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, the fetchAll methos of UrlFetchApp is used.

```js
function donorID() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('FileIDs');
  const ids = ss.getRange('C2:C' + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().filter(([c]) => c);
  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const requests = ids.map(donorId => ({
    url: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ssId}/externaldata/addimportrangepermissions?donorDocId=${donorId}`,
    method: 'post',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }));
  UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the cells "C2:C" of "FileIDs" sheet are valid Spreadsheet IDs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)

Comment: @Allan Henderson Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.